# Merge 2 collumn (Display suite) to one collumn depending on resolution

Tags: display-suite, theming

In a situation with display suite and two columns (left and right) I would like to accomplish to move everything to the left column and have the ability to reorder the fields.
In a classic situation the whole right column is moved under the left.
For example in the left column I have field1,field2,field3 in the right field4,field5,field6
When resolution is < 800 px I want to end up with a left column with field1,field4, field2,field5,field3,field6.
Not sure how I can make this happen, and any example or suggestion is welcome.

I think one option is to start with one collumn to begin with and build a 2 collumn situation like this: http://demos.wpmission.com/strong-testimonials/examples/two-columns-via-css-column/
But maybe there is other solution to use code to move and rearange the fields from the right to left ds column?

Thx a lot !

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would use a combination of 2 view modes plus [Context Mobile Detect](https://www.drupal.org/project/context_mobile_detect) to trigger the different view mode

Comment: Thx I'll give that a try, any preference for this module over context_breakpoint ?

Comment: None really, except breakpoint is still in beta

Comment: Yeah tried contex_breakpoint, work fine actually, but in the end it cannot be used cause it breaks drupal cache and the work around is damn ugly (adding get paremeters to url..)

Comment: could not get mobile detect to work.. I tought off another solution, to display some fields double using display suite and then use display:hidden depening on the resolution in a media query, that will work, but is not great either browsers still load hidden images apparantly... :-(